# Random data extensions: How to create more than 12

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, split

I need to split a data extension into 80 random data extensions, but have just realized that [**creating a random data extension**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_for_exacttarget_marketing_cloud/creating_a_random_data_extension/) from a selected data extension only allows up to 12 splits.

If any of you have ever found yourself in a similar situation, what did you do?

Comment: Have you tried using SOAP calls?

Comment: Interesting question Felix. Can you provide more information: why you need 80 (evenly split?) groups, and how you intend to use them? A/B testing, dynamic content or offers, etc. More information will help us find you a better answer :)

Comment: Hi Data_Kid - No SOAP is totally new to me. I'll look into it!

Hi Cameron - Sure. I have a data extension with approx 80K dutch addresses, but one of them is blacklistet or a spam trap - So every time we do a full send to that data extension, we get a lot of bounces.
To avoid regular adresses from recieving to many bounces, I'd like to split that send into 80 small sends to quickly identify the address causing the problems. Then I can ex- and import that data extension and repeat splitting until I have found the address and am able to exclude it.

Does it make sense? Thanks

Comment: Why not just query the [_bounce data view](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_bounce/) to find the problem email address(es)?

Comment: Hi @AdamSpriggs - Query is (as SOAP and REST) new to me, but I see some columns in the link below that might give me more data, than what I can see from **reason** and **description** when checking my bounces in My Tracking for that Job ID.

I'll give it a try and see if it helps, thanks

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_bounce/

Comment: @CameronRobert - found a solution.
I create my dutch data extension from filtering an import of data from Navision. In Navision, I had the programmer to create an extra field to each data entry being a random number between 1 and 80. Then I created filter activities to filter the dutch data extension into 80 small data extensions.

I admit, it's more a workaround than it's a solution, but it's something that I can use right away

Comment: Glad you found a resolution - however I agree with @AdamSpriggs approach; If your goal is to identify bounces, your best approach is to identify them specifically with a query and either suppress them from future sends - or update their subscriber status to "Held" (to prevent further sends). Query activities (SQL) are a fundamental part of intermediate-advanced Salesforce Marketing Cloud; I recommend you take the time to learn it. Best of luck!

Comment: @CameronRobert - I'm certainly looking into queries too. I've done _bounce queries and actually, have done a lot of _complaint queries appending complaints from the 11 dutch sends we've had trouble with. By doing this, I've managed to identify 52 complaint, some unique, some not, and by actually reacting to these I'll be able to maintain a cleaner environment. Getting to know queries has helped me a lot already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just wanting to ID bad bounces, then I'd create a Data Extension with the fields listed on the [_Bounce Data View page](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_bounce/) (plus an emailName, text(100) column and all columns nullable) and a Query Activity to populate it. A query something like this:

```
select
  b.AccountID
, b.OYBAccountID
, b.JobID
, b.ListID
, b.BatchID
, b.SubscriberID
, b.SubscriberKey
, b.EventDate
, b.IsUnique
, b.Domain
, b.BounceCategoryID
, b.BounceCategory
, b.BounceSubcategoryID
, b.BounceSubcategory
, b.BounceTypeID
, b.BounceType
, b.SMTPBounceReason
, b.SMTPMessage
, b.SMTPCode
, b.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
, b.TriggeredSendCustomerKey
, j.emailName
from _bounce b
inner join _job j on j.job_id = b.jobid
where jobid in (123456, 123457)
/* action: overwrite */
```

I'd export the DE and pull it into Excel and summarize it by `BounceType` to ID the largest group.  Once you know the largest, you can filter the worksheet by that to see if you can identify a problem domain.

You can determine the domain of an email with an Excel formula like this:

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",A2))
```

Comment: Hi Adam.

Did a send today and tried a Query on all bounces.
2724 of 2820 bounces are almost equally divided to 4 main dutch domains, ziggo, casema, quicknet and home.

They all share the SMTPBounceReason **5.3.2 (system not accepting network messages) mx1.tb.mail.iss.as9143.net mx1.tb.mail.iss.a9143.net ESMTP server not available** and even though this doesn't help me find a specific bad address, it does extend my knowledge of what I can do and how I can access information of my bounces. This is very useful, thank you